# Blank page in /help/account / Пустая страница в /help/account

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

In the help center, the page [ru.so.com/help/account](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/account) is completely empty.

Is this because of the sites combining or is it a mistake?

---

Страница [Справка / Моя учётная запись](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/account) совершенно пустая.

Это из-за объединения сайтов или это ошибка?

Comment: We haven't translated all the help center yet. We are working on it, mods and account sections on the way.

Comment: Okay then :) I know of a few russian speakers who may like to help - is any needed or is it covered at the moment?

Comment: We do all translation on the ["old Meta"](http://meta.hashcode.ru/users/480/silencer). If somebody wants to join it's okay. Just add a topic which you wanna to translate as a question first in order to avoid intersections.

Comment: @VenZell Thanks for all the edits across my posts!